# Aggregate daily level data to weekly level in R

Tags: r, date, xts, zoo

I have a huge dataset similar to the following reproducible sample data.

```
   Interval    value
1  2012-06-10   552
2  2012-06-11  4850
3  2012-06-12  4642
4  2012-06-13  4132
5  2012-06-14  4190
6  2012-06-15  4186
7  2012-06-16  1139
8  2012-06-17   490
9  2012-06-18  5156
10 2012-06-19  4430
11 2012-06-20  4447
12 2012-06-21  4256
13 2012-06-22  3856
14 2012-06-23  1163
15 2012-06-24   564
16 2012-06-25  4866
17 2012-06-26  4421
18 2012-06-27  4206
19 2012-06-28  4272
20 2012-06-29  3993
21 2012-06-30  1211
22 2012-07-01   698
23 2012-07-02  5770
24 2012-07-03  5103
25 2012-07-04   775
26 2012-07-05  5140
27 2012-07-06  4868
28 2012-07-07  1225
29 2012-07-08   671
30 2012-07-09  5726
31 2012-07-10  5176
```

I want to aggregate this data to weekly level to get the output similar to the following:

```
   Interval           value
1  Week 2, June 2012  *aggregate value for day 10 to day 14 of June 2012*
2  Week 3, June 2012  *aggregate value for day 15 to day 21 of June 2012*
3  Week 4, June 2012  *aggregate value for day 22 to day 28 of June 2012*
4  Week 5, June 2012  *aggregate value for day 29 to day 30 of June 2012*
5  Week 1, July 2012  *aggregate value for day 1 to day 7 of July 2012*
6  Week 2, July 2012  *aggregate value for day 8 to day 10 of July 2012*
```

How do I achieve this easily without writing a long code?

Comment: You used the [xts] tag, but it doesn't look like you have an xts object.  You're right though that xts is probably the simplest way to do this.  Did you search at all?  Look at `to.weekly`, `apply.weekly`, `period.apply` and search SO for the same.

Comment: It is important to note that the OP wants to aggregate by *week of the month* --- not by *week of the year*. Most of the answers below are based on week of the year.

Answer (score 17):

If you mean the sum of of ‘value’ by week I think the easiest way to do it is to convert the data into a xts object as GSee suggested:

```
data <- as.xts(data$value,order.by=as.Date(data$interval))
weekly <- apply.weekly(data,sum)

            [,1]
2012-06-10   552
2012-06-17 23629
2012-06-24 23872
2012-07-01 23667
2012-07-08 23552
2012-07-10 10902
```

I leave the formatting of the output as an exercise for you :-)

Comment: How can i now switch to a ts() object in order to use forecast and decompose?

Comment: Use the "as" method: `as.ts(data)`

Answer (score 6):

I just came across this old question because it was used as a dupe target.

Unfortunately, all the upvoted answers (except [the one by konvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629373/3817004)  and [a now deleted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629032/3817004)) present solutions for aggregating the data by *week of the year* while the OP has requested to aggregate by *week of the month*.

The definition of *week of the year* and *week of the month* is ambiguous as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587644/3817004), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43806987/3817004), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320136/3817004).

However, the OP has indicated that he wants to count the days 1 to 7 of each month as week 1 of the month, days 8 to 14 as week 2 of the month, etc. Note that week 5 is a stub for most of the months consisting of only 2 or 3 days (except for the month of February if no leap year).

Having prepared the ground, here is a `data.table` solution for this kind of aggregation:

```
library(data.table)
DT[, .(value = sum(value)), 
       by = .(Interval = sprintf("Week %i, %s", 
                                 (mday(Interval) - 1L) %/% 7L + 1L, 
                                 format(Interval, "%b %Y")))]
```

> ```
>            Interval value
> 1: Week 2, Jun 2012 18366
> 2: Week 3, Jun 2012 24104
> 3: Week 4, Jun 2012 23348
> 4: Week 5, Jun 2012  5204
> 5: Week 1, Jul 2012 23579
> 6: Week 2, Jul 2012 11573
> ```

We can verify that we have picked the correct intervals by

```
DT[, .(value = sum(value),
       date_range = toString(range(Interval))), 
   by = .(Week = sprintf("Week %i, %s", 
                             (mday(Interval) -1L) %/% 7L + 1L, 
                             format(Interval, "%b %Y")))]
```

> ```
>                Week value             date_range
> 1: Week 2, Jun 2012 18366 2012-06-10, 2012-06-14
> 2: Week 3, Jun 2012 24104 2012-06-15, 2012-06-21
> 3: Week 4, Jun 2012 23348 2012-06-22, 2012-06-28
> 4: Week 5, Jun 2012  5204 2012-06-29, 2012-06-30
> 5: Week 1, Jul 2012 23579 2012-07-01, 2012-07-07
> 6: Week 2, Jul 2012 11573 2012-07-08, 2012-07-10
> ```

which is in line with OP's specification.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "rn   Interval    value
  1  2012-06-10   552
  2  2012-06-11  4850
  3  2012-06-12  4642
  4  2012-06-13  4132
  5  2012-06-14  4190
  6  2012-06-15  4186
  7  2012-06-16  1139
  8  2012-06-17   490
  9  2012-06-18  5156
  10 2012-06-19  4430
  11 2012-06-20  4447
  12 2012-06-21  4256
  13 2012-06-22  3856
  14 2012-06-23  1163
  15 2012-06-24   564
  16 2012-06-25  4866
  17 2012-06-26  4421
  18 2012-06-27  4206
  19 2012-06-28  4272
  20 2012-06-29  3993
  21 2012-06-30  1211
  22 2012-07-01   698
  23 2012-07-02  5770
  24 2012-07-03  5103
  25 2012-07-04   775
  26 2012-07-05  5140
  27 2012-07-06  4868
  28 2012-07-07  1225
  29 2012-07-08   671
  30 2012-07-09  5726
  31 2012-07-10  5176", drop = 1L)
DT[, Interval := as.Date(Interval)]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you were to use `week` from `lubridate`, you would only get five weeks to pass to `by`. Assume `dat` is your data,

```
> library(lubridate)
> do.call(rbind, by(dat$value, week(dat$Interval), summary))
#    Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
# 24  552    4146   4188 3759    4529 4850
# 25  490    2498   4256 3396    4438 5156
# 26  564    2578   4206 3355    4346 4866
# 27  698     993   4868 3366    5122 5770
# 28  671    1086   3200 3200    5314 5726
```

This shows a summary for the 24th through 28th week of the year. Similarly, we can get the means with `aggregate` with

```
> aggregate(value~week(Interval), data = dat, mean)
#   week(Interval)    value
# 1             24 3758.667
# 2             25 3396.286
# 3             26 3355.000
# 4             27 3366.429
# 5             28 3199.500
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a data frame, you can easily do this with the `tidyquant` package. Use the `tq_transmute` function, which applies a mutation and returns a new data frame. Select the "value" column and apply the xts function `apply.weekly`. The additional argument `FUN = sum` will get the aggregate by week.

```r
library(tidyquant)

df
#> # A tibble: 31 x 2
#>      Interval value
#>        <date> <int>
#>  1 2012-06-10   552
#>  2 2012-06-11  4850
#>  3 2012-06-12  4642
#>  4 2012-06-13  4132
#>  5 2012-06-14  4190
#>  6 2012-06-15  4186
#>  7 2012-06-16  1139
#>  8 2012-06-17   490
#>  9 2012-06-18  5156
#> 10 2012-06-19  4430
#> # ... with 21 more rows

df %>%
    tq_transmute(select     = value,
                 mutate_fun = apply.weekly,
                 FUN        = sum)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>     Interval value
#>       <date> <int>
#> 1 2012-06-10   552
#> 2 2012-06-17 23629
#> 3 2012-06-24 23872
#> 4 2012-07-01 23667
#> 5 2012-07-08 23552
#> 6 2012-07-10 10902
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "aggregate" the values, you mean take their sum? Let's say your data frame is `d` and assuming `d$Interval` is of class `Date`, you can try

```
# if d$Interval is not of class Date d$Interval <- as.Date(d$Interval)
formatdate <- function(date)
    paste0("Week ", (as.numeric(format(date, "%d")) - 1) + 1,
        ", ", format(date, "%b %Y"))
# change "sum" to your required function
aggregate(d$value, by = list(formatdate(d$Interval)), sum)
#            Group.1        x
# 1 Week 1, Jul 2012 3725.667
# 2 Week 2, Jul 2012 3199.500
# 3 Week 2, Jun 2012 3544.000
# 4 Week 3, Jun 2012 3434.000
# 5 Week 4, Jun 2012 3333.143
# 6 Week 5, Jun 2012 3158.667
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple generalised way to aggregate at any time unit is to simply
calculate the time difference between time and min(time), truncate it and add it to min(time).

```
library(lubridate)
index <- min(data$Interval)

units <- "weeks"
num <- 1

unit_duration <- do.call(duration, list(units))

time_diff <- (interval(index, data$Interval) / unit_duration) / num

index + do.call(duration, setNames(list(trunc(time_diff) * num), units))
 [1] "2012-06-10" "2012-06-10" "2012-06-10" "2012-06-10" "2012-06-10" "2012-06-10" "2012-06-10" "2012-06-17" "2012-06-17"
[10] "2012-06-17" "2012-06-17" "2012-06-17" "2012-06-17" "2012-06-17" "2012-06-24" "2012-06-24" "2012-06-24" "2012-06-24"
[19] "2012-06-24" "2012-06-24" "2012-06-24" "2012-07-01" "2012-07-01" "2012-07-01" "2012-07-01" "2012-07-01" "2012-07-01"
[28] "2012-07-01" "2012-07-08" "2012-07-08" "2012-07-08"
```

For full weeks you can use `lubridate::floor_date()` on the index.

```
index <- lubridate::floor_date(index, unit = "week", week_start = 1)
time_diff <- (interval(index, data$Interval) / unit_duration) / num

time_agg <- index + do.call(duration, setNames(list(trunc(time_diff) * num), units))
time_agg
 [1] "2012-06-04" "2012-06-11" "2012-06-11" "2012-06-11" "2012-06-11" "2012-06-11" "2012-06-11" "2012-06-11" "2012-06-18"
[10] "2012-06-18" "2012-06-18" "2012-06-18" "2012-06-18" "2012-06-18" "2012-06-18" "2012-06-25" "2012-06-25" "2012-06-25"
[19] "2012-06-25" "2012-06-25" "2012-06-25" "2012-06-25" "2012-07-02" "2012-07-02" "2012-07-02" "2012-07-02" "2012-07-02"
[28] "2012-07-02" "2012-07-02" "2012-07-09" "2012-07-09"
```

You can then use that vector as your groups to calculate any summary.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(time_agg) %>%
  group_by(time_agg) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(value))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  time_agg     sum
  <date>     <int>
1 2012-06-04   552
2 2012-06-11 23629
3 2012-06-18 23872
4 2012-06-25 23667
5 2012-07-02 23552
6 2012-07-09 10902
```