# Week Number to Month Name Conversion

Tags: r, date

I have the following  data frame. How do I convert the week numbers to months. I don't want a date(mm-dd-yyyy). I am thinking of writing a loop but 
any better suggestions are welcomed.

```
    Week product  quantity
0    1    coke       1.5
1    3    fanta      1.7
2    7    coke       3.6
3    23   sprite     2.4
4    26   pepsi      2.9
```

This is the result i'd like to achieve.

```
   Week product  quantity  Month
0    1    coke       1.5   January
1    3    fanta      1.7   January
2    7    coke       3.6   February
3    10   sprite     2.4   March
4    13   pepsi      2.9   April
```

Comment: Take a look at `lubridate::month( x, label = TRUE, abb = FALSE )`, where `x` is your vector of dates parsed from the week number via `lubridate::ymd( "2017-01-01" ) + lubridate::weeks( c(1,3,7,10,13) )`

Comment: I'd like to have multiple opinions on how best to tackle this problem . Please remove the duplicate classification

Comment: If you want the month names after the solution using `as.Date/paste` in the link given, use `strftime` with `format = "%B"`.

Comment: I've just tested the new solution of @ArtemSokolov and the months are different. With `as.Date/paste`, the last month is June, with `lubridate` it's July. (Year is 2014.)

Comment: Oh, sorry. You want to subtract `1` from your `df$Week`, because `2014-01-01` is already week 1: `lubridate::ymd( "2017-01-01" ) + lubridate::weeks( c(1,3,7,10,13) - 1 )`. It's basically 0-based vs. 1-based indexing.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Yes, that does it, the two results are now the same.

Comment: Do you have a start date of your observations?  Is there agreement on which day starts the week?  Are you ok with the weeks that straddle two months being "given" to one of those two months?

Comment: Beware of the different conventions on how to count week-of-the-year. Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587644/3817004) for a discussion.