# Convert YYYY Www to a date field

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe field with as date field that is a factor with the following format "2019 W01", "2019 W02", "2019 W03".
how can I transform it into a date field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to first clean the dates from strings using `gsub`, then add `1` for first day of the week and convert `as.Date` using `format="%Y%U%u"` option.

```
x <- c("2019 W01", "2019 W02", "2019 W03")
as.Date(paste0(gsub("\\D", "", x), 1), format="%Y%U%u")
# [1] "2019-01-07" "2019-01-14" "2019-01-21"
```

This answer bay be considered as a special case of an [older relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587644/6574038).