# Date conversion format in R

Tags: r, date, format

Hi i need to pass from character to date format
My date in chr format is like : "2020-W14"
so i need to pass it to date format

I m trying  this with lubridate package;:

```
year_week="2020-W14"

date=as_date(year_week,format="%Y-W%W")
```

I get this date from this chunk of code but it is incorrect

2020-01-16

Any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the ISOweek package:

```r
library(ISOweek)


year_week="2020-W14"


ISOweek2date(paste0(year_week, "-1")) #add a reference day

#> [1] "2020-03-30"
```

See [Transform year/week to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object) for a detailed explanation.

<sup>Created on 2021-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much this was valid for this case

Answer (score 1):

`lubridate` stores dates in days, so expects to also get a weekday.

```r
library(lubridate)
year_week <- "2020-W14-0" # Sunday of 14th week

date <- as_date(year_week,format="%Y-W%W-%w")

## "2020-04-05"
```

Answer (score 0):

library(ISOweek)

year_week="2020-W14"

ISOweek2date(paste0(year_week, "-1")) #add a reference day

#> [1] "2020-03-30"