# How to prevent R turning 2021-01-01 into week number 2021-53?

Tags: r, date

I ran into something peculiar. I wanted to extract week numbers from dates.

Look what happend with the january 1st:

```
strftime(as.Date("2021-01-01"), format = "%Y-%V")
[1] "2021-53"
```

Obviously this not right.
What happens here and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object/45587644#45587644) for different definitions of week.

Comment: How are you defining week number? When does the week number increase? Is it every seven days? Every sunday? Is it OK if the first week doesn't have 7 days?

Comment: @MrFlick yes it is okay the first week doesn't have 7 days, and I start the week on monday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`53` is correct because `2021-01-01` is in the 53rd week of 2020 by the [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) system.  Week 53 runs from 2020-12-28 through 2021-01-03, inclusive.

`2021` is *incorrect*.  It is not the 53rd week of 2021, but rather the 53rd week of 2020.

The problem is that you are using `%Y` for the year.  When combined with the week number, you should instead be using `%G` for the year.  [See the docs here.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime)

Also, the ISO 8601 standard requires a `W` before the week number to be fully compliant.  Change your format to `"%G-W%V"` and it will correctly produce `"2020-W53"`