# How do I convert a date column that looks like this '202101' to '01-2021' in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a a column in R that is called 'Year Week' that shows yearly data and Week Data. 202101 represents the first week in 2021. However, I am try to format it into '01-2021' or '2021-01 to put it in a time series.

Comment: I think this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `my()` function from **lubridate**. Here's the cheatsheet: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/lubridate.pdf

Answer (score 2):

**1) Base R** Assuming the input is numeric as shown below use sprintf as in the code below.  No packages are used.

```
x <- 202101
sprintf("%02d-%d", x %% 100, x %/% 100)
## [1] "01-2021"
```

**2) yearmon** Another approach is to convert it to yearmon class and then format it.  x is defined above.

```
library(zoo)

format(as.yearmon(as.character(x), "%Y%m"), "%m-%Y")
## [1] "01-2021"
```

**3) sub**  Another base approach is

```
sub("(....)(..)", "\\2-\\1", x)
## [1] "01-2021"
```

**4) read.fwf** Yet another base approach is:

```
with(read.fwf(textConnection(as.character(x)), colClasses = "character", c(4, 2)), 
  paste(V2, V1, sep = "-"))
## [1] "01-2021"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub`:

```r
gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})", "\\2-\\1", 202101)
#R> [1] "01-2021"
```