# unexpected behaviour of as.Date() with %W format

Tags: r, week-number, as.date

I thought I had understood how I can use `as.Date()` but I get an unexpected result when using the UK convention for counting weeks in a given year (`%W`).

I have a year-week combination and want to find the date corresponding to Monday and Sunday of that week (if they exist, so it's fine that `NA` is returned if the week does not contain Mon or Sun). In the UK week counting, the week starts with a Monday. So to find the Monday of, say, week 1 in 2016, I use the following code, which returns the correct result (4 Jan 2016):

```
as.Date("2016011", format = "%Y%W%u")
```

To find the Sunday of that week, I change the last number to 7 because `%u` takes 1 to be Monday and 7 to be Sunday (I have also used `%w` instead with its definition of Sunday 0 and Monday 1 but with the same result):

```
as.Date("2016017", format = "%Y%W%u")
```

My expected output is 10 Jan 2016 but I get 3 Jan 2016. So it seems that `as.Date()` treats the week as beginning with Sunday. This however contradicts the definition of `%W`.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: If you want Sunday to be the first day of the week, use `%U`. From the documentation of `?strptime`: *"%U
Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Sunday as the first day 1 of the week"*. And `as.Date("2016017", format = "%Y%U%u")` is the same date as `as.Date("2016010", format = "%Y%W%w")`. Both `"2016-01-03"`.

Comment: This link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object

Comment: Try `as.Date("2016027", format = "%Y%U%u")`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I don't want Sunday to be the first day of the week. The data I am using has chosen the UK convention, i.e. Monday as the first day of the week. Thank you for the suggestion of how to obtain the correct days. I have used a similar workaround (using the Sunday from next week) but my question was more about why the function does not behave as I understood it.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I had read the post and the answers before. I believe my expectation of what the function should return is consistent with their explanations but the function returns something different.

Answer (score 0):

For working with dates, I recommend the `lubridate` package.
Below are some examples.

```
library(lubridate)

date1 = ymd("20160103")
weekdays(date1)  #Local name of the day of the week
#[1] "niedziela"

wday(date1)      #Weekday number regional setting
#[1] 1

wday(date1, week_start = 1) #Weekday number where Monday is 1 day
#[1] 7
```

You can set `lubridate.week.start` option to control this parameter globally.

[Here's](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/day.html) a bit more information.

Comment: Also `isoweek()` and `isoyear()` from the lubridate package for working with ISO8601 dates. I've not yet found a function to convert from iso week to a date (eg. monday of the iso week) in the lubridate package.