# Convert from character to date in a "YYYY-WW" format in R

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I have a hard time converting character to date in R.

I have a file where the dates are given as "2014-01", where the first is the year and the second is the week of the year. I want to convert this to a date type.

I have tried the following

```
z <- as.Date('2014-01', '%Y-%W')
print(z)

Output: "2014-12-05"
```

Which is not what I desire. I want to get the same format out, ie. the output should be "2014-01" but now as a date type.

Comment: "2014-01" cannot be changed to date type because "2014-01" is not a valid date. An R date has only 1 valid format which is `YYYY-MM-DD` anything else is of character type.

Comment: A date requires a year, month and day, so a day and a week cannot be of type Date. You may want to distinguish between _storing_ a date versus _displaying_ a date as a string with a given format. [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object) show how to convert year-week to Date, but to display a Date object as year-week you would use format _e.g._ `format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%W")`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are dealing with some version of year week, which exists in three forms in `lubridate`:

> week() returns the number of complete seven day periods that have
> occurred between the date and January 1st, plus one.
>
> isoweek() returns the week as it would appear in the ISO 8601 system,
> which uses a reoccurring leap week.
>
> epiweek() is the US CDC version of epidemiological week. It follows
> same rules as isoweek() but starts on Sunday. In other parts of the
> world the convention is to start epidemiological weeks on Monday,
> which is the same as isoweek.

Lubridate has functions to extract these from a date, but I don't know of a built-in way to go the other direction, from week to one representative day (out of 7 possible). One simple way if you're dealing with the first version would be to add `7 * (Week - 1)` to jan 1 of the year.

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(yearweek = c('2014-01', '2014-03')) %>%
  tidyr::separate(yearweek, c("Year", "Week"), convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0(Year, "-01-01")) + 7 * (Week-1))

  Year Week       Date
1 2014    1 2014-01-01
2 2014    3 2014-01-15
```