# Transform a "Year-ISO Week" character object to a Date object

Tags: r, as.date

I've been having some struggles with dates. Namely, being able recognize a variable (as a `Date`variable) that has dates registered by the following manner: Year-ISO week. So the following code:

```
class("2021-20")
```

Idealy should return: `Date` .

The following code recognizes it as a `date`, but it returns a date that I don't understand where it comes from. And even if I try with other dates (different values of the ISO week), I always get the same response:

```
as.Date("2021-20", format = "%Y-%W")
[1] "2021-12-13"
```

I've tried transforming "normal dates" to the format year-iso week, but it leads to no where, I can never get it to be recognized as a `Date`object, and I need to perform `ggplot2`graphs.

This question was linked to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object), although the question itself is very similar, I am still **not able** to get the result I desire.

Comment: If you think the linked answer doesn't work for you, you should show what you tried using that post. Otherwise it's unclear why that and lots of other posts on converting dates wouldn't work

Comment: What date (month,day,year) should "2021-20" return? From the duplicate, it looks like `as.Date(paste0("2021-2","-1"), format = "%Y-%W-%w")` would work. The format needs to uniquely point to a particular date.

Comment: Another potentially relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74683149/6851825

Comment: As the linked answer indicated, you need to specify a day of week to make your code specify a single date: `lubridate::isoweek(as.Date("2021-05-17")); as.Date(paste0("2021-20", "-1"), "%Y-%W-%w")`

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself correctly. The main goal is to plot a ggplot2 line graph where the ISO weeks are represented in the x-axis. So I needed to have `R` recognize them as Dates. The answers on other posts don't maintain the "Year - ISO Week" format whilst simultaneously having `R` classify them as Dates.

Comment: @JonSpring thank you for providing that question! I have the same issue,  and it leads me to believe that my requested can't be fulfilled: "An R date has only 1 valid format which is YYYY-MM-DD anything else is of character type." as someone pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in the comments, R has a Date format that is always YYYY-MM-DD, so if you want to plot data with a date axis, it often makes sense to convert your format to that. But there's nothing preventing you from subsequently formatting the Date data to display with an arbitrary other format. This will change the display appearance on the axis after the physical position mapping has occurred using the Date data.

So you can plot year-week data, but you have to take a detour to Date and then come back. As noted in related questions, year-weeks include 7 days, so to convert a year-week to a Date you need to specify which day of the week to use; that's the "1" in the paste part.

In the example data below, I've added gaps so you can see how the Date data is mapped correctly to the timeline.

```
data.frame(year = c(rep(2021,8), rep(2022, 3)),
           week = c(45:52, 1, 3, 5),
           val = 1:11) |>

  ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(paste(year, week, 1, sep = "-"), "%Y-%W-%w"),
             y = val)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "week", date_labels = "%Y-%W", name = "year-week")
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent thinking! Finally got what I wanted, thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: If I may ask, why do we include the "1" in the paste function? It noticed it changes the dates if I replace it another value.

Comment: Year-weeks include 7 days, I am picking which day of the week to make it a specific day.